# How to split an ASP.NET project into different editions with different modules

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, architecture, module

Suppose that there's an ERP System that holds the following modules:

1. Personnel
2. Time and Attendance
3. Payroll
4. Social Care
5. Training

This ERP system is built using a layered architecture of ASP .NET web forms (DAL, BLL, BVL, GUI). The backend is SQL Server and is accessed through EF. There's ONE database holding all the tables of all modules, and a lot of these tables are co-related. There's ONE GUI project for all modules. But each module is put in a separate folder.

My target is to create different editions with different modules. For example (Personnel + Time and Attendance + Payroll), or (Personnel + Payroll + Social Care), etc.

The question is: is there a guide or a best-practice to achieve this target? How to maintain published code, how to isolate DB tables that are not needed?

Comment: Do you have a log in system? From your question it seems like each edition would have its own set of modules? Edition 1 would have modules Personnel, Time/Attendance, and Payroll, while Edition 2 would have Personnel, payroll, and social care? How are you determining which edition to use? Are you using Editions as revisions? Wouldn't it be more simple to design some sort of log in system and you make the decision of which module to display off of the users permissions?

Comment: Starter:  Database side, I would create schemas to encapsulate different functionality.   That way you can have them in one database, but have a seperation, and know exactly when you cross those boundaries lines.

Comment: @Brandon J
There's already a login system. Currently I use it to allow/deny access to specific modules. The problem is, the security configuration are all stored in the DB, so any one who has access to the DB server may give himself the permission to access all the modules if he wish.

Comment: If you're concerned just about licensing, you can have the configuration in db encrypted (ie. UserLicenses table where there will be UserID and encrypted list of modules user has access to).

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a system that works already. If the security concern now is "Some db admins may do stuff they shouldn't", then will you remove that concern with the "Several editions" plan?

Answer (score 0):

Put the module code in different class libs and use dependency injection to tie the modules together.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 1 database, separate class library projects for each of the module and a single presentation layer.